# Add label automatically on transition/state change

Tags: jira

Ho do I add Label automatically on transition/state change.
E.g I need to add label 'done' when state changes to 'Fixed'

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use postfuction in issue workflow when issue moving to fixed.

[image]